# Syntax of "Best Before"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I know the meaning of the "Best before" tag on food products. However, I am a bit uncertain how to interpret the phrase as a language construct. Is it a simple elision like "[consume] best before *date*"? Or is "best" perhaps a verb here?

Comment: It's telegraphese. It could stand for 'Best eaten before' (still a reduced form ... from 'This food would be at its best if eaten before' / 'It would be best to eat this food before' / ...). But with such deleted forms, the original can often merely be guessed at, meaning the question is a matter of opinion. // However, telegraphese is often used, and totally acceptable where there is no real possibility of misinterpretation (*'Best thrown away before ...').

Comment: Technically, _best_ is an adjective. Here it's a predicate adjective, and the rest of the sentence has been thrown away to get the label right.

Comment: You asked for the syntax: it's adj+prep, a short form of "best eaten before", or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ([Cambridge dictionnary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/best-before-date)) **best-before date**  noun [ C ]  COMMERCE   UK
> (US **best-if-used-by date**)
> the date after which food or drink begins to lose its quality or taste:

Here is one likely short prototype:

- It is best to consume before

However, there is no necessity to confine oneself to a particular form. The following is as well an option.

- this product is best if consumed before

---

*As a mere abbreviation of several possibilities (from **user Djin Tonic**, see comments)*

- (This) item/product/… (is) at its **best before [date]**

Comment: You can get to it directly with *This item is at its **best before [date]**.*

Comment: Funny I thought "best" could be a verb (absurd) or an adverb (as in "consume this best before _date_") but I didn't think it could be an adjective as in "this product is best before _date_". :-) Thank you all for the explanation.

Comment: @Sixtease In fact, "best" (usually the superlative of "good") has been turned into a verb (to defeat or be better than somebody). ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/best_4)) In this locution, however, there is no way to consider "best" as the verb form.